# Quarkus Webservice with Apache CXF and Basic Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, basic-authentication, quarkus

I'm developing an application with Quarkus (1.9.2) and i have to provide a SOAP Webservice to an external company. From this external company I got a WSDL-file and I use Apache CXF to create the webservice basic implementation.

I have to secure this webservice with basic authentication, but I don't know how to implement this. Do I need to create an interceptor or is basic authentication something that needs to be specified in the WSDL-File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CXF leverages the Spring framework and Spring Security is an easy way to add basic authentication for your webservice.

Btw. the latest CXF release contains some optimizations for GraalVM and Quarkus. There is also a community extension (in case you are not already using it): https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkiverse-cxf